# how to save image of loaded keras model as png/jpg?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a keras model and saved it to later make predictions. However, I loaded the saved model using:

```
from keras.models import load_model

#Restore saved keras model
restored_keras_model = load_model("C:/*******/saved_model.hdf5")
```

Now I would like to save an image of the loaded model so I can visualize it before using it before making predictions.

Is there a way of doing this in keras or is the use of another library required?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in addition to doing a restored_keras_model.summary(), you can save the model architecture as a png file using the plot_model API.

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(restored_keras_model, to_file='model.png')
```

https://keras.io/visualization/#model-visualization